# Rails: `undefined method `per_code' for nil:NilClass` When Chaining Info From Different Object Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating an admin page for my app in which there is a table that shows `user` data.  Each `user` has completed several quizzes.  In each quiz (`per_quiz`, `bal_quiz`, etc.) there is a code that needs to be reported on this page (the columns are `per_code` in the `per_quiz` model, `bal_code` in the `bal_quiz` model, etc.

Each `user` `has_one` `bal_quiz` (and `per_quiz` and so on) and each `per_quiz` `belongs_to` a `user`.

I'm trying to call it like this:

```
<% @users.each do |u| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= u.id %></td>
    <td><%= u.first_name %></td>
    <td><%= u.last_name %></td>
    <td><%= u.per_quiz.per_code %></td>
    <td><%= u.bal_quiz.bal_code %> (Balance)
      <br><%= u.flex_quiz.flex_code %> (Flexibility)
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

In my `controller` I have `@users = User.order("last_name DESC")`.

The error I am getting is `undefined method 'per_code' for nil:NilClass` called on the `<td>` line of the view.

Can anyone help me figure out why this isn't working?  I have similar `erb` elsewhere in the app and this syntax works...

Comment: it isn't working because `u.per_quiz` is returning `nil`. What happens if the user has not taken the `per_quiz` yet? What is the value then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's due to `u.per_quiz` equals to nil. Use [try](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/Object/try) to solve this problem:

```
<td><%= u.try(:per_quiz).try(:per_code) %></td>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'll have to remember `try`... That seems like it would fix a lot of issues...